# Creating a date specific URL or page in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, date, dynamic

I have lots of experience with databases, scripting and even writing .net web pages, but not much of Wordpress beyond the obvious or what I can find a plugin to do. So I am hoping that some of the more experienced WP'ers can point me in the right direction.

Problem.

I want to present a document (either as a pdf or docx using a plugin) to the user that changes with the date. To be specific it is an Sunday Order of Service which changes with the liturgical season( Christmas, Easter, Pentecost, Ordinary Time).

In .Net I would create a data structure (table, Hash, associative array or something matching the date,  or date range ,  document URL, ( and possibly liturgical colour and Day Name), this would need an annual update as Easter moves around. Then I would query this using the current date and display a page URL or add a shortcode to the page.

Is this sensible, feasible and not too hard? Is there an easier approach?

Thanks for your help and any ideas.

I have had a search for a useful plugin and looked up creating custom tables, but this mostly seems to be about displaying static data, whereas i am trying to generate date specific URLs or pages.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you can do this yes. PHP will directly be able to "grab" that URL and you can do whatever you want with it. This is the simplest way to get the current URL.

```
global $wp;
$current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request));
```

Now you could create a specific page as mentioned from you, and then either forward somewhere, or add a document to the page.

Comment: Thank you,  need to think about that a bit and work out how to add some PHP to the WP instace.